# How to fix Parse error-> unexpected ';', expecting '(' in *C//directory* on line 2

Tags: php

My first php file and encountered this. Help! On line 2 there seem to be a problem and I need to submit my work soon. I am in real need of help.

```
<?php
 require_once '../workspace/dboperation.php'; 

  $response= array();
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
  {
    if(isset($_POST['username'])and
         isset($POST['email']) and
              isset($POST['password'])
      )
      $db= new dboperation();
      if($db->createUser(
        $_POST['username'],
        $_POST['email'],
        $_POST['password']
      )){
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])and
     isset($POST['email']) and
          isset($POST['password'])
  ) <==== YOU MISSED `{`
  $db= new dboperation();
```